# Exception Handling in Power apps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I am trying to handle an exception in Power Apps. If the scenario fails I want the control to show the error screen.

Below is the code I using. Please advise on how to make this work.

```
IsError(
    Filter(Idea_Master,
        Idea_Status in ListBox2.SelectedItems.Value && 
        Idea_Category in ListBox2_1.SelectedItems.Value,
        SearchTextBox_1.Text in Idea_Title || 
        SearchTextBox_1.Text in Initiator || 
        SearchTextBox_1.Text in Idea_Category || 
        SearchTextBox_1.Text in Idea_SubCategory || 
        SearchTextBox_1.Text in Idea_Id
    ),
    Navigate(ErrorScreen,ScreenTransition.Fade)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would use the `Filter()` function to **collect** a subset of data from a Data Source or in a **display** function, filtering information for the user.

`Filter()` will not return an error statement.

Its difficult to understand where this code would sit in your app.

- Is it the `Items` property of a Gallery?
- Or a check on the `OnSelect` code of a "Submit" button?

Something you may use `OnSelect` of the "Submit" button is:

```
If(
    IsEmpty(
        Filter(dataSource,
            column1 = condition1,
            column2 = condition2,
            etc...
        )
    ),
    Navigate(scrError, Fade)
)
```

[`IsEmpty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-isblank-isempty#isempty) denotes a blank table of data.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank You Bro.. Will try and let you know

Answer (score 0):

The IsError function tests for an error value.
Using IsError will prevent any further processing of the error.

You can use the following code:

```
If(
    CountRows(Filter(Idea_Master,
        Idea_Status in ListBox2.SelectedItems.Value && 
        ...
    ))=0,
    Navigate(ErrorScreen,ScreenTransition.Fade)
)
```